# Why would a C program need two scanf with same definition.Can somebody explain it?

Tags: c, macos

This is the code.Check Line 5 in the code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
float occurence(char array[],char searched);
int main(){
    /*char new[] = "NITTE"; */
    char new[100];
    char *point = & new[0];
    char query;
    printf("String:\t");
    scanf("%s",point);  //THIS CAUSES ERROR BUG HERE!!!.ALONG WITH "char new[100]" IN THE LINE ABOVE.
    /*printf("Search:\t");*/
    scanf("%c",&query);
    printf("Search:\t");    
    scanf("%c",&query);
    printf("String =\"%s\"\nQuery =\"%c\" ",point,query);

    //printf("%c",*(point+1));
    for(int i = 0 ; *(point+i)!='\0';i++ ){
        if(*(point+i)==query){
            static char * add;
            add=&new[i];
            printf("Position:%d\nAddress:%p \n", i+1,add);
        }
    }
    printf("Occurance in String = %f %%\n",occurence(new,query));
    return 0; 
}
float occurence(char array[],char searched){
    float appearance = 0,occurance=0;int i=0;
        for(i=0;array[i]!='\0';i++){
            if(array[i]==searched){
                appearance++;
            }
        }
    float length = i;
    appearance=appearance+0.0;length=length+0.0;//THIS IS THE ONLY WAY I COULD THINK OF CONVERTING INT TO FLOAT SINCE
    //                                          APPEARENCE WOULD RETURN 2 AND 2.O AND SAME GOES FOR THE LENGTH.
    occurance = (appearance/length)*100;
    return occurance;
}
```

HERE two scanf s are needed but it has the same definitions.
Explain with details No short answer please.

Comment: On the 8th line, you don't need to use an ampersand with %c specifier. And you must use an ampersand with %s.

Comment: @Jabberwocky DIY. You'll get to know the differences between using %c and %s with/without ampersand in scanf().

Comment: Also `char *point = & new[0]` is just a od way to write `char *point = new`

Comment: But why? @LinuXMan

Comment: @LinuXMan - I suggest you do it yourself. You got it backwards

Comment: `scanf("%c",&query);` will read the newline or other whitespace that terminated `scanf("%s",point);` but it would not need to be twice if you add a space thus: `scanf(" %c",&query);` before the `%`. That is not clear because of a line break so i will type it again: `scanf(" %c",&query);`

Comment: so you mean to say you don't need & when using %c in scanf? @LinuXMan

Comment: "/THIS CAUSES ERROR BUG HERE!!!.ALONG WITH "char new[100]" IN THE LINE ABOVE." - *what* is the error?  Is it a compiler error, a runtime error, what?

Comment: You must not use it for `%s` but you do need it for `%c`.

Comment: @LinuXMan it's the other way round

Comment: How is it pointless? @Jabberwocky

Comment: @Learner I removed the first comment which was not very clear. It's pretty pointless to have `scanf("%c",&query);` twice.

Comment: Plus one thing, what error are you getting and what's your desired output? That's not clear to give a satisfy answer. Please edit your post.

Comment: If I Comment the one scanf.It doesn't accept any values after entering the values for String:

Comment: @Learner pease read my comment which answers your question. `scanf` leaves a newline char in the buffer.

Comment: Wow you are right. @WeatherVane Thanks

Comment: But Why did that happen? why type scanf(" %c",&query) instead of scanf("%c",&query)

Comment: The format specifiers `%d` and `%s` and `%f` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[...]` and `%n` do not. But you can instruct `scanf` to do so by adding a space just before the `%`. The `scanf` conversion stops at the first character it cannot convert, which is typically (but not necessarily) a space or a newline, and that character remains in the input buffer. Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Answer (score 1):

in your first `scanf()` at this line

```
    /*printf("Search:\t");*/   scanf("%c",&query);
```

cathes newline char `\n`, and again your second `scanf()` at this line

```
    printf("Search:\t");    
    scanf("%c",&query);
```

catches your input.

You should leave a space for get rid of first `scanf()` like this

```
    scanf(" %c",&query);
```

thanks to the `white space`, it skips newline char `\n` and gets correct input.